# Convert an Excel to TIFF file

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, tiff

I have an Excel file with pixel values and I'm trying to convert it to TIFF or raster dataset to be opened with Arcgis. I looked here for similar problems and I could not find any. I tried something but it gave an error. Excel file obtained from `DEM`  include `2098 rows x 2851 columns` without heading.

Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import Image as im    

file = r'C:/Users/owrasa/PycharmProjects/den/demrep2.xlsx'
size = 2098, 2851
df = pd.read_excel(file, header=0)
df2 = pd.np.array(df)
imarray = im.fromarray(df2)
imsave = im.SAVE(imarray, "TIFF")
```

Here is the error message:

> TypeError: Cannot handle this data type

The Excel file looks like this:

```
-32767  -32767  -32767  -32767  -32767  -32767  -32767  -32767  -32767  -32767  -32767  -32767  -32767  -32767  -32767
-32767  -32767  -32767  -32767  -32767  -32767  -32767  -32767  -32767  -32767  -32767  -32767  -32767  -32767  -32767
-32767  -32767  -32767  -32767  -32767  -32767  -32767  -32767  -32767  -32767  -32767  -32767  -32767  -32767  -32767
-32767  -32767  -32767  -32767  -32767  -32767  -32767  -32767  -32767  -32767  -32767  -32767  -32767  -32767      60
-32767  -32767  -32767  -32767  -32767  -32767  -32767  -32767  -32767  -32767  -32767  -32767  -32767      60      60
-32767  -32767  -32767  -32767  -32767  -32767  -32767  -32767  -32767  -32767  -32767  -32767      60      60      60
-32767  -32767  -32767  -32767  -32767  -32767  -32767  -32767  -32767  -32767  -32767      60      60      60      60
-32767  -32767  -32767  -32767  -32767  -32767  -32767  -32767  -32767  -32767      60      60      60      60      60
-32767  -32767  -32767  -32767  -32767  -32767  -32767  -32767  -32767      60      60      60      60      60      60
-32767  -32767  -32767  -32767  -32767  -32767  -32767  -32767      60      60      60      60      60      60      60
-32767  -32767  -32767  -32767  -32767  -32767  -32767      60      60      60      60      60      60      60      60
-32767  -32767  -32767  -32767  -32767  -32767      60      60      60      60      60      60      60      60      60
-32767  -32767  -32767  -32767      60      60      60      60      60      60      60      60      60      60      60
-32767  -32767  -32767      60      60      60      60      60      60      60      60      60      60      60      60
-32767  -32767      59      60      60      60      60      60      60      60      60      60      60      60      60
-32767      59      59      59      59      60      60      60      60      60      60      60      60      60      60
    59      59      59      59      59      59      59      59      59      60      60      60      59      60      60
    59      59      59      59      59      59      59      59      59      59      59      59      59      59      59
    59      59      59      59      59      59      59      59      59      59      59      59      59      59      59
    59      59      59      59      59      59      59      59      59      59      59      59      59      59      59
    59      59      59      59      59      59      59      59      59      59      59      59      59      59      59
    59      59      59      59      59      59      59      59      59      59      59      59      59      59      59
    59      59      59      59      59      59      59      59      59      59      59      59      59      59      59
    59      59      59      59      59      59      59      59      59      59      59      59      59      59      59
    59      59      59      59      59      59      59      59      59      59      59      59      59      59      59
    59      59      59      59      59      59      59      59      59      59      59      59      59      59      59
    59      59      59      59      59      59      59      59      59      59      59      59      59      59      59
    59      59      59      59      59      59      59      59      59      59      59      59      59      59      59
```

Comment: Just guessing, but I suspect you might have more luck if you exported the file as a CSV from Excel.

Comment: A TIFF isn't a automatically a GeoTIFF. If you use the GDAL library you can set a projection, cell size, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code had several problems:

1. The `Image` module was not imported from `PIL`.
2. The data type of `df2` was `int64` rather than `int32`.
3. The call to `Image.save()` was incorrect (the function name has to be lowercase).

The following snippet fixes all those issues and should get the job done:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import PIL.Image as im

file = r'C:/Users/owrasa/PycharmProjects/den/demrep2.xlsx'
df = pd.read_excel(file, header=0)
df2 = pd.np.array(df).astype(np.int32)
imarray = im.fromarray(df2)
imarray.save(r'C:/Users/owrasa/PycharmProjects/den/demrep2.tif')
```

Comment: Thank you very much. l m new user and l m happy to learn my mistake here .